# read google email from telnet

Tags: email, cmd, smtp, telnet

```
C:\Users\Wild Beast>openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 CONNECTED(000001B8)
```

I got connected with the server and was able to login but when I use `list` command to read the mails. It showed the error

```
235 2.7.0 Accepted
list
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. m7-20020adfe0c7000000b002060e7bbe49sm16301005wri.45 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1):

SMTP on port 587 is used for submitting emails to the outgoing mail server and has no `LIST` command. You may want to look into POP3 or IMAP to fetch emails from the incoming mail server of your mailbox provider. Let me know if you need help with that.